# What happens to my phone service provider contract if I replace Android with Ubuntu?

Tags: android

I can't seem to easily locate an answer with google. I have the typical 2-year contract with Sprint on my Android phone. I'm curious how Ubuntu effects that? Does the 4G and sms/phone services stay with the phone even though the Android system has been replaced with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would of thought that it relies on the SIM card, not the phone... So it might stay the same, as long as you use the same SIM. It also depends on whether your [device is supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

Try checking with your provider, [Sprint](http://www.sprint.com/), to see if there is any terms & conditions on the phone contract. You should have got that in small print when you got the phone...

You can also [Contact them](https://mysprint.sprint.com/mysprint/jsp/landingPage/contactus.jsp)

Comment: You answered far more than I could have asked for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Mostly guessing, partly slight experience. I get my phones on Pay As You Go, then I can modify as I like ;D